# How to execute DDL/DDM SQL scripts In Redshift using Glue ETL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I am trying to read a sql script(myCreateInsertSqlScript.sql) in S3 bucket(myS3Bucket), and would like to execute that in Glue ETL. I used couple approaches below, it seems it only is executing Select statements which make sense as it saves the record in dynamic frame. Following code will success only if the script is a Select statement. But I want to execute a sql script having insert/create/select statements all in it. How or which library is the best to use for this task?

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
# Get the object
obj = s3.Object('myBucket', 'myCreateInsertSqlScript')
# Read the object's content
content = obj.get()['Body'].read()
# Convert the content to a string
string_content = content.decode('utf-8')

AmazonRedshift_node123 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="redshift",
    connection_options={
        "sampleQuery": string_content,
        "redshiftTmpDir": "myTempDir",
        "useConnectionProperties": "true",
        "connectionName": "MyConToMyRS",
    },
    transformation_ctx="AmazonRedshift_node123",
)
```